# "The file <APP_NAME.app> couldn't be opened because there in no such file."-ERROR

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: Error message]

When I tried to run my project on my iPhone I suddenly got this error message: 
"The file  couldn't be opened because there is no such file.". 
The code worked just fine some minutes before with the simulator.

I've tried tried to clean the build, restart xcode, even the computer, but it won't go away.
What could this message mean? And how do I solve it?

Comment: Do you have source control on the project? It looks like the info.plist may have been changed or something like that? Try deleting the app from the simulator and try it again?

Comment: I've done that. Now it won't run in the simulator either

Comment: Do you have source control? Something has been changed and I guess it's something with the info.plist. At a guess anyway.

Comment: Yes I have source control (luckily). I have done some changes in an other plist (not info.plist), but that I do all the time and this is the first time I've seen this error.

Comment: I was thinking more of the bits like `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`. Where has the string "NameOfTheApp" come from? Is that the actual error or have you altered it?

Comment: So, the image that you have put into the question. Is that edited? i.e. have you taken the actual name out of the screenshot? If not just search for "NameOfTheApp" in the project?!

Comment: Yes, I changed the app name.

Comment: Ah, that didn't help. You should just blur it out or something. At least tell us that you edited it. Or put the standard <Name of App> brackets around it so I can see it's edited.

Comment: Changed the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! Not an elegant one, but it works.
I simply renamed the app (clicked on the project name in the project navigator panel, and changed the name), and the app came back to life!

Comment: I had to rename it, and then rename it back to the original name to make it work

Answer (score 0):

After encountering the same issue, which couldn't be solved by renaming the app, I created a new project in Xcode and imported all files from the original project.
The issue disappeared and the application worked.